# XmlDocument loping (foreach) reomving NameSpace "xmlns"

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

hey guys I had XML file and I was using XDocument to write on it and using the next void remove the namespace

```
string path = Server.MapPath(xmlpath);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path)
XElement root = new XElement("url");
foreach (var node in doc.Root.Descendants()
                           .Where(n => n.Name.NamespaceName == ""))
                {
                    node.Attributes("xmlns").Remove();
                    node.Name = node.Parent.Name.Namespace + node.Name.LocalName;
                }
```

this function works 100% with the XDocument  now I changed

```
XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load(path);// the old doucument

XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument();//the new document
```

I need a function that allows me to make loping and remove the namespace xmlns from my nodes the same one like above thanks a lot for your time's guys and thanks a lot for reading my question

Comment: Could you share a sample xml and the result after removing the namespace?For more details about how to use XmlDocument,you could refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961886/11398810

Comment: Lets continue our discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208660/discussion-between-clint-and-darwiesh-mustafa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very *close*, just had to use  `XMLDocument.CreateElement(string Name)` overload which *returns* a `XMLNode` and then use `.InnerText` property to set your *value*

```
var mainRoot = doc.DocumentElement; //urlset element
var urlRoot = doc.CreateElement("url"); //create url element
var VidooTree = urlRoot.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(a, ""));
urlRoot.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("loc", "http:/domain/site.com"));
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(b)).InnerText="imgur";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(c)).InnerText= "videoTitle";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("video:description")).InnerText= "videoDec";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(d)).InnerText= "VideoApi";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(m)).InnerText= "duration";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(nn)).InnerText= "2050-11-05T19:20:30+08:00";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(e)).InnerText= "watched";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(k)).InnerText= "date";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(f)).InnerText= "yes";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(g)).InnerText="No";
VidooTree.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(h)).InnerText= "VideoKindName";
urlRoot.AppendChild(VidooTree);
mainRoot.AppendChild(urlRoot);
```

*Output*

```
<url xmlns="">
 <loc xmlns="http:/domain/site.com" />
  <video>
    <thumbnail_loc>imgur</thumbnail_loc>
    <title>videoTitle</title>
    <description>videoDec</description>
    <content_loc>VideoApi</content_loc>
    <duration>duration</duration>
    <expiration_date>2050-11-05T19:20:30+08:00</expiration_date>
    <view_count>watched</view_count>
    <publication_date>date</publication_date>
    <family_friendly>yes</family_friendly>
    <live>No</live>
    <category>VideoKindName</category>
  </video>
</url>
```

Comment: how to remove xmlns="" in  <url xmlns=""> and xmlns="" in  <loc xmlns="http:/domain/site.com" />

Comment: i did thats             urlRoot.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("loc")).InnerText = ""http:/domain/site.com" and it'sworking but how i can remove "xmlns" from <url xmlns="">